# How to create a UX Research Portfolio?

Tags: research, portfolio, examples

I am currently applying for UX positions that are mostly orientated around UX research but also include UX design in terms of wireframes, mockups, personas etc. I am now being asked to submit my portfolio of work with my applications but I do not have one unfortunately and need to create one.

My previous UX work was based on research and usability testing, and unfortunately I no longer have access to this work or have kept samples of it.

Any advice for creating a portfolio from scratch and what to include in it? Also what medium should I use to create the portfolio itself?

All advice or suggestions are most appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: See these posts for examples: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31055/how-to-showcase-ux-work ,  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15579/building-an-ux-design-portfolio , http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4662/thoughts-on-creating-a-portfolio/4667 http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33392/what-makes-a-great-user-experience-portfolio

Answer (score 4):

> My previous UX work was based on research and usability testing, and
>   unfortunately I no longer have access to this work or have kept
>   samples of it.

You can still reference any work you have done in the past as long as its not covered by **Non disclosure Agreement** and your work experience is verifiable.

> Any advice for creating a portfolio from scratch and what to include
>   in it?

Your Research portfolio should focus on:

- Demonstrating knowledge of different methodologies : The idea is to
  show employers which method you opted for in specific contexts
  (Quantitative/Qualitative) or more focused on (attitudes/Behaviour)
- Demonstrating the process used to define research goals: how you
  came-up with your primary question. what other questions needed to be
  formulated in order to answer your primary question.
- Assumptions and hypothesis: How you derived these and what type of
  information you gathered to validate them: the focus here is on the
  type of data/information gathered (testing) and how they helped
  confirm or refute assumptions.

You could also conduct your own research in a subject of interest to demonstrate the above which will help convey your know-how and skills.

> Also what medium should I use to create the portfolio itself?

The medium is less important here as you are more focused on research compared to other UX deliverables ( knowledge of wire framing tools etc.)

That being said, in principle your choice should help you illustrate your thought process and demonstrate your communication skills such as the ability to translate, synthesise requirements and findings into easily digestible chunks of information or conceptual models that other team members or stakeholders could use.

Hope that helps